# Extremely long delay before my android app displays the splash screen

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, build, delay

When I try to run my app in the emulator it takes like 4-5 seconds until the splash screen appears. Can somebody help me to reduce this time? or will it disappear after i build the app? i tried everything but couldn't find a solution.
Am i missing something in the code?

here is the splash screen code:

```
package com.bigfamilydevelopers.saverforall.activity;


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
SplashScreen activity;
Context context;
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;
AppLangSessionManager appLangSessionManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    context = activity = this;
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);
    appLangSessionManager = new AppLangSessionManager(activity);
    UpdateApp();

    setLocale(appLangSessionManager.getLanguage());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    activity = this;
    appLangSessionManager = new AppLangSessionManager(activity);

    appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
            try {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                        appUpdateInfo, IMMEDIATE, activity, 101);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void HomeScreen() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }, 1000);

}

public void UpdateApp() {
    try {
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(IMMEDIATE)) {
                try {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            appUpdateInfo, IMMEDIATE, activity, 101);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                HomeScreen();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
            HomeScreen();
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            HomeScreen();
        } else {
            HomeScreen();
        }
    }
}


public void setLocale(String lang) {
    if (lang.equals("")){
        lang="en";
    }
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);



}


}
```

Comment: well a run does do a complete compile of your project, it does essentially build it, so it's quite normal for there to be _some_ delay, it's definitely not instant

Comment: I think you have to provide some code then we can tell you if there is any issue, or it is normal for Android Studio to run it so long

Comment: @noname Sorry, here is the splash screen code. Please check the code and get back to me.

Comment: code look ok, except the line ` context = activity = this;` pointless assignment in activity, where you can use `this` or `getApplicationContext()` whenever possible. I think the time of running application can change when you build apk and install on the device. Also it would be worth to check if your `AppUpdateManager` does not do anything cheeky.